# Page content not translated in WordPress REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, wpml

I don't have expertise in WordPress.

http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages

This is my api which gives me all pages and their content.

But I have used WPML plugin to multiple languages.

And I'm trying to get page content in other languages but it's not working. Like:

http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?lang=fr

But it works in WooCommerce, like in categories, products and orders etc. But not working in static pages.

Comment: do you use URL format as directory, like example.com/fr/ or as parameter like example.com?lang=fr?

Comment: I am using as parameter like example.com?lang=fr?

Comment: Please help on this.